# How to check if overflow occurs in risc-v addition?

Tags: overflow, addition, riscv

To check overflow after multiplication in RISC-V, we can use `mulh` and `mulhu`. But how can one check overflow after `add` or `sub` instruction?

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways is to ask a compiler.  This page shows gcc built-in functions:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

---

Unsigned overflow test code:

```
bool unsigned_overflow ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int c;
    return __builtin_uadd_overflow ( a, b, & c );
}
```

And here's what RISC-V (32-bits) gcc 13.2.0 says with -O3:

```
unsigned_overflow(unsigned int, unsigned int):
    add     a1,a0,a1
    sltu    a0,a1,a0
    ret
```

Unsigned overflow occurs if the result is less than either input — you don't have to test both inputs; they'll both give the same answer, so one is sufficient.

---

Signed overflow test code:

```
bool signed_overflow ( int a, int b )
{
    int c;
    return __builtin_sadd_overflow  ( a, b, & c );
}
```

And here's what RISC-V (32-bits) gcc 13.2.0 says with -O3:

```
signed_overflow(int, int):
    add     a5,a0,a1
    slt     a5,a5,a0
    slti    a1,a1,0
    sub     a0,a1,a5
    snez    a0,a0
    ret
```

Signed overflow occurs if the result is less that one input and the other input is not negative, or vice versa.

(I don't know why they don't provide a single instruction for testing signed overflow.)

---

You can do the same with the built-in subtraction functions.

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:27,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:27,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:27,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:27,startLineNumber:4),source:%27++++bool+unsigned_overflow+(+unsigned+int+a,+unsigned+int+b+)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++unsigned+int+c%3B%0A++++++++return+__builtin_uadd_overflow+(+a,+b,+%26+c+)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++bool+signed_overflow+(+int+a,+int+b+)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++int+c%3B%0A++++++++return+__builtin_sadd_overflow++(+a,+b,+%26+c+)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A%0A++++%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:rv32-gcc1320,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+RISC-V+(32-bits)+gcc+13.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+RISC-V+(32-bits)+gcc+13.2.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)